# Python Requests Form Data Adding Content Length to each Request

Tags: python, python-requests, multipartform-data

Here's roughly how the request looks through fiddler. I can see two additional parameters being sent which i cannot send programatically using python.

```
    --13155ffa-71a1-4e80-b213-dd238786ee20
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="image.jpeg"
    Content-Type: image/jpeg
    Content-Length: 8557

   --13155ffa-71a1-4e80-b213-dd238786ee20
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lat"
    Content-Length: 6

    18.975
    --13155ffa-71a1-4e80-b213-dd238786ee20
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="long"
    Content-Length: 10
```

The first is Content-Length and the second is Content-Type under the file. Is it possible to do this in requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As stated in the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file), the Content-Type can be set by passing a three-element tuple as a value of the `files` dict, e.g.,:

```
requests.post(
    url,
    files={
        'image': ('image.jpeg', filehandle, 'image/jpeg'),
        'lat': ('filename', filehandle, 'text/plain'),
        'long': ('filename', filehandle, 'application/octet-stream'),
    },
)
```

You cannot set the Content-Length header, as requests sets it automatically for you.  The only reasons to use a different Content-Length than the one requests sets would be if (a) requests got the length wrong, in which case you should file a bug report, or (b) you want to lie to the server you're sending the data to, which is wrong.